# Showing that a function is a class function

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Define

$f:G \to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(g)=|\{h \in G:h^2 = g \}|$. I want to prove that $f$ is a class function, i.e. we want to show that

$|\{h \in G:h^2 = g \}|=|\{k \in G:k^2 = xgx^{-1} \}|$.

I am really not sure how to do this. We know that conjugation by $x$ is an automorphism, but I'm not sure how to use this fact here. I don't see how does the number of squared group elements equal to some given $g$ is the same as the number of squared group elements equal to the conjugate of the same $g$ by some $x \in G$. Could someone help?

Comment: Conjugation by $x$ is an automorphism of $G$. So if $g$ has exactly $k$ square roots, then so does $xgx^{-1}$.

Comment: It is simple, you can consider x=1 to have that the two sets are equal

Comment: When we take $x=1$ this is obvious, but $x$ can be anything ( in $G$). I feel really silly for not seeing this immediately..

Comment: When I conjugate $g$ by some $x$ it will give me an element $k \in  G$, s.t. possibly $k \neq g$. Why can I then say that $k$ will have exactly as many square roots as $g$?

Comment: Like Lord Shark says, it's because the map $\phi : G\to G$ defined by $\phi(g) = xgx^{-1}$ is an isomorphism. Hence, there is a bijection between solutions to $h^2 = g$ and $h^2 = \phi(g),$ given by $h\leftrightarrow\phi(h)$